# R: Variable lengths differ

Tags: r, time-series, lm

I'm trying to create a linear model based off a time series analysis such as the following:

Model 1 = novice_crash ~ time + grad + time.after + month

I have the following code that creates the variables in question above:

```
grad<- c(replicate(66,0),replicate(30,1))
grad<- ts(grad, start=c(2002,1), frequency=12)

time<- seq(1,96, by=1)
time<- ts(time,start=c(2002,1), frequency = 12)

time.after<- c(replicate(66,0),replicate(30,1))
time.after<- ts(time.after, start=c(2002,1), frequency = 12)

#month<- seasonaldummy(novice_crashes)
month<-time

grad.lag1<- lag(grad)

time.after.lag1<- lag(time.after)
```

'novice_crashes' is a ts object that comes from the following code (where 'crashes' is a csv file

```
novice<- crash$novice_crash
total<- crash$total_crash
novice_crashes<-ts(novice, start = c(2002,12), end=c(2009,12), frequency = 12)
```

When I try to run this `model1<- lm(novice_crashes ~ time + grad + time.after + month)` I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = novice_crashes ~ time + grad + : variable lengths differ (found for 'time')
```

I have checked the lengths of time, grad, time.after and month (which are all 96 units long).

The dataset `crash` had NA's present but I removed with

```
crash<- na.omit(crash)
```

Im much more used to python so I may be missing something here...

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Supply data for `crash` in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter code here`I agree with the comment of MrFlick. But from what you said you did not check the lenght of the variable of `novice_crashes`. Since this time series starts later (`start = c(2002,12)`) compared to the others (`start = c(2002,1)`). Maybe there is the problem.

Let me know if this was the problem and otherwise post a reproducible example.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for looking over, you were correct in that I accidentally had put 2002,12 instead of 2002,1. I will take the comment of MrFlick for next time